# How to automatically source a program

Tags: linux

I installed Gromacs in Linux, but I should use the command:

$ source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC

to be able to work with software.
How can I automatically source that file, so I won't need to use this command everytime I open the terminal?
Best

Comment: By doing it in your shell's startup scripts.

Comment: sorry, I am really new to both Linux and Gromacs. Can you please describe in more detail?

Comment: Start by reading [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) and then pick a suitable file in which to add the command.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt say which linux distro your using but i will go ahead and say its ok to run this command, If you wish to source this file when you login to your graphical environment

```
echo "source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC"  >> /etc/profile
```

Or if you just wish to source it when you open a new bash shell in the terminal

```
echo "source /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC"  >> ~/.bashrc
```

I just saw in your question you wanted to source it during a new terminal shell start, therefore the second command (bashrc) is the one you want, and the comment below is true, if you have problems with the source command try

```
echo ".  /usr/local/gromacs/bin/GMXRC"  >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you need any of this explaining just comment back and ill do my best for you, hope it works see you

Comment: Note that `source` won't work with POSIX sh.

Comment: @Sean Davey thank you very much. The second command worked. I just need to know what is a bash environment, and I'll search it. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, if it worked please consider to choose my answer as the selected answer, and I can watch my points go up (slowly) and smile :) .... and by "by what is a bash environment" I think you are referring to a "shell" . If so, this will help you... http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/basic-shell-reference